# Joomla website google reindex title

Tags: seo, title, google-search

I have problem with one of my websites running on CMS Joomla - http://www.luxusni-apartman.cz when I wrote this website to [**google search**](https://www.google.cz/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=luxusni%20apartman&es_th=1) it show this website with old title and because of that I have problem with SEO optimalization, can you help me? This version of website is running for 3 months, before there were old version with different title.

If I change description or keywords google change it and show correctly. What is wrong? How to force Google to change title? Thank you ...

Comment: Could you include an example?

Comment: Google may not show your title and show what they think is best : http://searchenginewatch.com/sew/news/2342232/why-google-changes-your-titles-in-search-results

Comment: unor | Example? If you write to google [luxusní apartmán](https://www.google.cz/search?q=luxusn%C3%AD+apartm%C3%A1n&oq=luxus&aqs=chrome.3.69i60l3j69i59j69i60l2.4241j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) in the results there is my website with old title, which I used to use before, on old version of website. But title of new website is completly different and I dont know how to force google to change it ... there is big SEO problem because of that ....

Comment: user29671 | Thank you for this interesting information, I've never noticed that google change titles like this ... but my problem is different I guess cos google use old title, title from old version of website....